# meaning of the verb "log" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/_-SckJKAEQs). It is at around 9 minute and 31 second. Here is the context:

> He does this one a little bit differently in terms of the weights you use, and the the volume that you use on it. And the rep totals that you are **logging** on here.

I have checked all the meanings of it in [The Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/log) but still have a hard time understanding what the coach means there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**logging** seems to mean, perhaps figuratively rather than literally, "adding to a log maintained in a training regimen".  You may not be writing anything down, just noting mentally the number of whatever you're doing. I think you might paraphrase it as "accumulating" or "tallying".

Comment: I find it very common to hear *I've logged many hours on (the machine / the track  / the court)*. While the example sentence is phrased slightly differently, I don't find it outside the mainstream. In fact, I'd find *accumulating* to be less normal.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: are you taking **rep totals** as equivalent, functionally, to **hours**? That is, they are *what* is being logged. And **on here** to be like **on the track** or **on the court**?  If so, to what does **here** refer? The gym?   *You are logging hours **on here*** sounds very strange to me.

Comment: Yes, you can "log" any number of things. Enemies kills in a video game, hot dogs eaten in a contest, reps, or hours. (Although some of those things wouldn't sound natural in such a construction because we simply don't refer to them that way—or, at least I don't . . .I probably shouldn't make such a universal statement given our different perspectives.) All I can say is that the expression in the question doesn't sound strange to me. No doubt because I've heard it used a lot in that sense. I assume that the rep totals are being logged on "the weight machine."

Comment: But doesn't **logging** in the sense you're using it (e.g. hours on the court) mean much the same as "putting in" something which can be *tallied*?  We wouldn't say "I've been logging **effort** on the tennis court".

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm using it. And while I've always said and heard "logging **hours** on the tennis court" rather than **effort**, hearing **effort** in that sentence sounds perfectly natural to me. In short, *logging X (on / at) Y* is a very common phrase here (in Ontario, Canada—or at least where I've lived specifically), and is quite idiomatic.

Comment: @Jason Bassford:  *Logging hours at the gym* is common enough here in Pennsylvania too.  As I said, it is a figurative usage, since you're not actually logging these hours in a log, but accumulating them.

Comment: We also say "*racking up*" in a similar way. ;)

Comment: Exactly, That's heard too, but no "rack" is involved :)  I've removed the "not mainstream" bit.